# Restier (Odata) expand + count & top not working

Tags: asp.net, odata, kendo-ui-grid, restier

I'm actually using Restier 0.4.0-rc2 and I have an issue while expanding my entities.

Example :

```
http://localhost/odata/ire/Users?$count=true
```

Everything is correct, count is 97

```
http://localhost/odata/ire/Users?$count=true&$top=10
```

Still ok, count is 97

```
http://localhost/odata/ire/Users?$count=true&$top=10&$expand=Group
```

No more ok, count is now 10.

It is an issue cause my pagination is no more working in my kendo ui grid.

I don't know how to fix that issue, I've done a lot of search on google and no solution for my problem..

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue and it has been fixed now, https://github.com/OData/RESTier/issues/287

Restier 0.5.0 rtm will fix this issue.